# Expose Properties through method and not directly

Tags: c#

I've a very simple requirement

```
public class A
{
   public int Index{get;set;}

   public B ConfigOne{get;set;}
   public B ConfigTwo{get;set;}

  public void SetConfigOne(string val1, string val2);
  public void SetConfigTwo(string val1, string val2);
}

public class B
{
   public string Val1{get;set;}
   public string Val2{get;set;}
}
```

How do I arrange my two classes, so that I should be able to do this :

```
  var a = A.ConfigOne.Val1;
```

but not

```
A.ConfigOne.Val1 = a;
```

so basically I want to make my indirect class (B) properties readOnly, still settable inside the class A. 
I want to expose the setter through a method. How do I do that?

Comment: public B ConfigOne{get;private set;}  ???

Comment: [Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) is currently very sad.

Comment: basically the idea is, that I don't want anyone to play around with the properties, still for the ease of usage, I need to have it in internal classes. and no @Stef, tht would not allow me to set it inside A

Comment: You could make `B` immutable and make `ConfigOne` and `ConfigTwo` have `private set`. When you want to change values from `A`, you'd need to construct new `B` instances though

Comment: The only feasible solution that I see is to actually inherit from `B` and make the setters `protected`--but that would likely defeat the remainder of your needs.

Comment: Your question seems to be contradicting. You say "but not `A.ConfigOne.Val1 = a;` Then you say, "I want to make my indirect class (B) properties readOnly, still settable inside the class A. As far as I can tell, these two statements contradict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an interface that exposes only a read-only view onto the data that `B` can implement.  This means that anyone with a direct reference to the `B` object can set its data, but when accessed from the property in `A` it will be read only:

```
public interface IReadValues
{
    string Val1 { get; }
    string Val2 { get; }
}

public class A
{
    public int Index { get; set; }

    public IReadValues ConfigOne { get; set; }
    public IReadValues ConfigTwo { get; set; }

    public void SetConfigOne(string val1, string val2);
    public void SetConfigTwo(string val1, string val2);
}

public class B : IReadValues
{
    public string Val1 { get; set; }
    public string Val2 { get; set; }
}
```

By not using a auto-property, an instead having `A` have fields of type `B` that are exposed through explicit properties you can ensure that the `A` class can modify these objects as well.

Comment: @Servy I see. like internally in `A`'s constructor or something like that?

Comment: Nice. Nothing to stop `((B)a.ConfigOne).Val1 = "mad hax"` though, right?

Comment: @Blorgbeard In this example, no.  You could do it if it was a serious concern, but generally there isn't a reason to prevent that type of thing.  If it is really that important, you simply need to create a new wrapper object that holds onto an instance of `B` and re-directs the property calls to the underlying instance.  This can't be cast back to a `B` directly though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the built in parameter accessors. Doing so through methods is kind of atypical. Making the setter private means that it is accessible only from that class like any other private object.

```
public class A
{
   public int Index{get;set;}

   public B ConfigOne{get; }
   public B ConfigTwo{get; }

}

public class B
{

   public B(string val1, string val2)
   {
       this.Val1 = val1;
       this.Val2 = val2;
   }
   public string Val1{get; private set;}
   public string Val2{get; private set;}
}
```

Comment: Will it be settable in class A?

Comment: Doesn't prevent setting `A.B.Val1`, only `A.B`

Comment: Right, I made the wrong setter private. This arrangement will suit him better. This prevents `A.B.Val1`. `B.Val` is only settable through itself now.

Comment: But he wants to be able to set `B.Val` from `A`?

Comment: @Blorgbeard He can set them from within the constructor in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that it cannot be made. When you make the statement:

```
A.ConfigOne.Val1 = a;
```

you **actually expose an object of class B** by the statement

```
A.ConfigOne
```

and then you set the property Val1. If the property is not settable, then it cannot be set.

If you want the property of B to be set only from specific classes, then you should a method and not a property. For example:

```
public class A
{
   public int Index{get;set;}

   public B ConfigOne{get;set;}
   public B ConfigTwo{get;set;}

   public void SetConfigOne(string val1, string val2);
   public void SetConfigTwo(string val1, string val2);


   //This method exposes the new functionality
   public void setVal1OfConfig1(string value){
       ConfigOne.Val1 = value;
   }
}

public class B
{
   protected string Val1{get;set;}
   protected string Val2{get;set;}
}
```

In this case, only classes from the same assembly could change the value of the TempProperty. Therefore, the class A should be on the same assembly. Check [access modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) to see your options.

Hope I helped!